# Vue router with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, vue.js, plugins, vue-router

I'm creating a plugin with Vue for Worpdress, and having some issues. I'm using Vue Router and everything looks okay, until a nested route is not accessed directly. The problem is that nested Vue Route are not found (404) if accessed directly.

For example:

Main application stands in: **myhost.com/auction**

And I have a route for single page:**myhost.com/auction/lot/{some_params}**

So if I try to access **myhost.com/auction/lot/{some_params}** directly, wordpress tries to find page **{some_params}**, I need to ignore this behavior.

I tried with .htaccess but no luck. As I understand probably rules needs to be rewritten that everything after auction/ should go as request to auction/ and then router should work.

Here is my router:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/auction',
      name: 'main',
      component: Main,
    },
    {
      path: '/auction/lot/:params',
      name: 'single',
      component: Single,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

What I need that a nested route to be accessible directly.